# How to install the stock Browser app on Nexus 7 (2013)?

Tags: nexus-7, stock-browser

I would like to run the stock Android Browser app on a Nexus 7 (2013) tablet to make sure that websites that I develop will work properly in the stock Browser. However, a Nexus 7 (2013) tablet comes with Chrome pre-installed and not the stock Browser.

Is there a way to install the stock Browser app onto a Nexus 7 (2013) tablet without unlocking or rooting it?

Comment: http://www.guidingtech.com/23316/get-back-stock-browser-aosp-android/  That should work. There's links to apk also to side load. Chrome IS the stock nexus browser though. Also you have the AVD to test it out!

Comment: Thanks @RossC. True, I can test in the emulator for the most part, although I also needed to test multitouch events and could not get the [SdkController app](http://tools.android.com/tips/hardware-emulation) to work. Also, call me paranoid, but I didn't want to install a binary that I know relatively nothing about, so I decided to build the Browser app from source: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/20426383/how-to-build-the-stock-android-4-3-browser-from-source/

Answer (score 2, accepted):

[Link to stock browser apk](http://www.guidingtech.com/23316/get-back-stock-browser-aosp-android/)

The link contains the apk for the stock browser. Alternatively, as you have chosen you can build the stock browser from source also.

[How to build stock browser from source code, stackoverflow](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/20426383/how-to-build-the-stock-android-4-3-browser-from-source/)

Generally you can also use the [avd](/questions/tagged/avd) for testing the browser, but not if you need multi touch and other 'phone' related functionality.

Chrome is now the stock browser for [nexus](/questions/tagged/nexus) devices, and most OEMs (manufacturers) include their own version of the browser.